# How to reduce Wall time of the below query?

Tags: sql, sqlite, time-complexity

**(125, 3)
Wall time: 18min 18s**

```
    SELECT Movie.year AS Year, COUNT(*) AS NOM ,Movie.Title
    FROM MOVIE JOIN M_Cast ON TRIM(M_Cast.mid) = TRIM(Movie.mid) JOIN 
    Person ON TRIM(Person.pid) = TRIM(M_Cast.pid)
    WHERE Person.Gender = 'Female'
    GROUP BY Movie.year
    ORDER BY NOM DESC
```

*For each year, count the number of movies in that year that had only female actors*

Comment: Please add the text of the SQL, not a picture, so we can debug it or tweak it.

Comment: First of all, those `TRIM()` are preventing the use of typical indexes. On small data sets that won't be noticeable, but for big data sets that kills performance. Are the `TRIM()` functions necessary? Can you remove them?

Comment: Without using TRIM this query is giving the blank output

Comment: If all these ids need trimming do it with update statements. Then you will not need trim() in your query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your use of `trim()` is preventing the use of indexes.  You should *never* need this for joins between tables.  So:

```
SELECT m.year AS Year, COUNT(*) AS NOM , m.Title
FROM MOVIE m JOIN
     M_Cast c
     ON c.mid = m.mid JOIN 
     Person p
     ON p.pid = c.pid
WHERE p.Gender = 'Female'
GROUP BY m.year
ORDER BY NOM DESC ;
```

In a properly structured database, the ids in `MOVIE` and `PERSON` should be primary keys.  If they are not, you should fix that.

You also want an index on `M_CAST(mid, pid)` or `M_CAST(pid, mid)`.

If your primary keys are strings, you should fix that values so `TRIM()` is NEVER needed:

```
update movie
    set mid = trim(mid);
```